# How to group data in a Google Sheets spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables.

###### Table 1

| ID | FIRST NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A01 | John |
| A02 | Peter |
| B01 | Marta |

###### Table 2

***Note:*** This table purposely has more entries.

| ID | LAST NAME |
| --- | --- |
| A02 | Smith |
| B01 | Clevens |
| A03 | Rogers |
| A01 | Brown |

Both tables represent the same people with First Names and Last Names, identified by ID. How I can join the data into one table grouped by ID correctly?

Desired results

| ID | NAME | SURNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | John | Brown |
| A02 | Peter | Smith |
| A03 |  | Rogers |
| B01 | Marta | Clevens |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Single Formula Version `G2`

```
=SORT(MAP(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A2:A,D2:D)), LAMBDA(_id, 
  { _id, 
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(_id, A2:B,2,FALSE)),
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(_id, D2:E,2,FALSE)) }
 )))
```

1. Use [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) to join the **ID** columns from the two tables into a single combined ID column
2. Apply [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653) to the combined column to get the list of lookup values
3. [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) the lookup values into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function and assign an arbitrarily named variable `_id` to represent the mapped lookup values in the formula
4. Create a 1x3 array `{col1, col2, col3 }` for each mapped `_id` :
        **Col1:**  `_id`
        **Col2:**  `FIRST NAME` from [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) *****
        **Col3:**  `LAST NAME` from [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) *****
         <sub>***** [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) returns a blank instead of an error from VLOOKUP if value not found</sub>
5. Optionally [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) the resulting table by `_id` (in this formula) or other column as preferred.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think my first approach is to create a new table with all the unique ID, and use the VLOOKUP function to bring in the [NAME, SURNAME] columns into that new table.

[image]

If you're not familiar with VLOOKUP, it's a great function. This screenshot, should explain what it's doing better.

Obviously, I would put the new table in it's own sheet, I just put it all in one sheet for simplicity and to show you the examples.

[image]

Here is a link to a [Google Sheet with a VLOOKUP example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_U63LMGIzTLz-TGFddwno5ffc0S3D-j8_0iXhPNv3cs/edit?usp=sharing).